# Is there an option to have meson install missing dependencies? (For my GNOME Calendar build.)

Tags: gtk, gnome, ninja, meson-build

I am trying to build GNOME Calendar on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 system, and so I do

`$ meson ./gnome-calendar ./myGCbuild`

and then have been installing the missing dependencies that it tells me one by one using `apt`.

But eventually I run into some more "non-trivial" things such as that my `glib-2.0` version needs to be `>= 2.58.0` but the latest on `apt` repository is `2.56.3` and so guess I need to make another build of the latest `glib` or maybe find on `PPA`; but so I'm wondering:

Is there some way `meson` or something else can take care of automatically installing the missing dependencies with the right versions, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Meson isn't a dependency solver.  So, No, meson doesn't take care that.

However, if you want to build gnome applications, there is [The Newcomers Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers).  Check out [the Build Project](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildProject) page.  It tells you about "*[Flatpak](http://flatpak.org/), a technology for installing and distributing applications and an IDE called [Builder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder), which has good integration with GNOME technologies and Flatpak. This is the recommended method for new contributors, and is the easiest way to get started.*"

Happy Hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it fall back to a subproject and build the library as a private dependency, however that is not what you want in this case and no its not Mesons job to understand package managers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conan](https://conan.io/) to manage your third party dependency and then have meson call conan for fetching them.

Your conan file:

```
[requires]
glib/2.58.3@bincrafters/stable 

[generators]
pkg_config
```

And in your meson.build put:

```
run_command('conan', 'install', '--install-folder', meson.build_root(), meson.source_root, check: true)

glib_dep = dependecy('glib')
```

Answer (score -1):

Apt can do this for you: `apt-get build-dep gnome-calendar`.